# Colocar datos de un json en una lista desplegable en un modal

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap

Estoy creando con boostrap y javascript un modal y dentro de el tengo unas lista desplegables las cuales deben tener los nombres de los departamentos y mostrarlos en la lista, el problema es que no he podido lograr traer los datos desde el json https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/2pnw-mmge.json ya que estoy usando datos abiertos y no he podido lograr que con un filter me filtre los datos del jason y como mostrarlos en la lista, adjunto foto y codigo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en el código estoy usando templates en el javascript para crear el formulario en el metodo ejecutar y en el if de editar donde me va a salir el modal y poder elegir los deptos, cultivos y municipios de la lista desplegables, adjuntos la clase donde esta el metodo que me crea la tabla con el boton del modal, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
generarTabla(data){
    let strTabla = `<table class="table table-striped"
    id='data-eval-agropecuaria'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope = "col">Acción</th>
        <th scope = "col">Cultivo</th>
        <th scope = "col">Departamento</th>
        <th scope = "col">Municipio</th>  
        <th scope = "col">Producción</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
`;
data.forEach(element => {
    strTabla += `
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <a title="Ver" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-eye">&nbsp;</i></a>
            <a title="Editar" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-edit">&nbsp;</i></a>  
            <a title="Eliminar" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt">&nbsp;</i></a>
        </td>
        <td> ${element.cultivo}</td>
        <td> ${element.departamento}</td>
        <td> ${element.municipio}</td>
        <td> ${element.producci_n_t}</td>
    </tr>`;
});

strTabla += "</tbody></table>";
document.querySelector('#data-eval-agropecuaria-tabla').innerHTML = strTabla;

document.querySelectorAll('#data-eval-agropecuaria-tabla td a').forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.ejecutar(e, data);
        }));


  ejecutar(elemento, data){
    let fila = elemento.closest('tr').rowIndex;
    let accion = elemento.getAttribute('title');

    console.log(accion, fila, data[fila]);

    if(accion == 'Ver'){
        document.querySelector('#infofila-titulo').innerHTML = `${accion} Datos del agro`
        document.querySelector('#infofila-contenido').innerHTML = `
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cultivo</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=${data[fila-1].cultivo} disabled> 
            </div>
            <br>
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Departamento</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=${data[fila-1].departamento} disabled> 
            </div>
            <br>
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Municipio</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=${data[fila-1].municipio} disabled> 
            </div>
            <br>
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Producción</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=${data[fila-1].producci_n_t} disabled> 
            </div>
            <br>
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Período</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=${data[fila-1].periodo} disabled> 
            </div>             
                `
        $('#infofila').modal('show')
    }

    if(accion == 'Editar'){
        document.querySelector('#infofila-titulo').innerHTML = `${accion} Datos del agro`
        document.querySelector('#infofila-contenido').innerHTML = `
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cultivo</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">

                  </select>
            </div>
        <br>
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Departamento</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                  </select>
            </div>
        <br>
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Municipio</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                  </select>
            </div>
        <br>
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Producción</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Editar producción"> 
        </div>
        <br>
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Período</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Editar periodo"> 
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <button type="button" id="btnenviar" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Actualizar datos</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        `
        $('#infofila').modal('show')
    }

    if(accion == 'Eliminar'){
        console.log('Eliminar esta fila');


    }
}
```

Comment: Muy interesante la propuesta solo tengo una pregunta simple ya que hizo todo ese movimiento de filtrar y etc etc.. te queda alguna estructura similar a esto:

Comment: echo '<option  value="'.$id.'">'.$verdura.'</option>';}

Comment: Nada, solo del json que tengo necesito en el select del if "Editar" filtrar los datos del json para que me aparezca en la lista desplegable

Comment: En cuanto a la ventana modal no debe representar mayor problema precisamente en estos momentos estoy desarrollando un sistema y parte del proyecto lo desarrollo sobre modales bootstrap donde tengo varios selects, uno dependiente de otro en dos niveles cargados desde Mysql  y dos cargados en el cuerpo del modal directamente y otro sin dependencia cargado desde Mysql

Answer (score 1):

Precisamente a eso me refiero para que un select despliegue su contenido debe tener esta forma al menos:

```html
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

cada elemento que se va a mostrar debería estar dentro de un `<option></option>` al menos es la forma que conozco y que se encuentra definida en:[Select](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/select)
por eso mi cuestionamiento de si lo tienes construido como en mi primer intervención eso significa que debes hacer un barrido por cada uno de los registros del Json desde el 0 al 999 y sacar tus datos, hacer el "cuerpo de lista" y mostrarlo la otra forma que te mostré en mi comentario `echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$verdura.'</option>';` viene de una consulta mysql y dentro de un ciclo para que haga la lista de los elementos visibles. Si existe otra manera de hacerlo lo desconozco.  Como quiera me llamo mucho la atencion este proyecto que expones y bueno me gustaría conocer la solución que puedas llegar a tener.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me faltaba ese detalle pero igual aun no he logrado hacer el barrido por los registros del json y sacar esos datos, hacer el cuerpo y mostrarlo, soy estudiante de ingeniería de Sistemas y estoy empezando con esto de la programación web y mi profesor me dijo que con un filter los sacaba pero no he podido

Comment: @GustavoAndresPavaParra encontre algo similar a lo que requieres, solo que esta en ingles, haber si te puede ayudar a resolver este problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery  .  Animo!!!